# Limit of a sequence satisfying $(2-a_n)a_{n+1} \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This was in one of the calculus textbook exercise problem. Now, I am pretty sure that there was a typo in the problem.

**Problem**

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying the following:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (2-a_n)a_{n+1} = 1.
$$
Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n= 1$.

**My tries**

1. The conclusion is true under assumption of $0<a_n<2$ for all but finitely many $n$.
2. The conclusion is false without any further assumption. So, the problem is incorrect as it is stated.

**Question**

Is the conclusion true under an additional assumption of boundedness of $a_n$?

**Remarks**

I was able to obtain a sequence $a_n$ that the conclusion is false. However, under the assumption of boundedness, I am wondering if we can prove the conclusion or give a counterexample.

**Proof of My try 1**

Let $\overline{a} = \limsup a_n$ and $\underline{a} = \liminf a_n$. Let $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a subsequence of natural numbers such that $a_{n_k}\rightarrow \overline{a}$. Then we have 
$$
(2-a_{n_k}) a_{n_k +1} \rightarrow 1.
$$
Taking a convergent subsequence of $\{a_{n_k +1}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $b$, we have 
$$(2-\overline{a}) b = 1.$$
This gives $b=1/(2-\overline{a})$. Since $\overline{a}$ is the limsup, we have
$$
\frac1{2-\overline{a}}\leq \overline{a}.
$$
By assumption $0<a_n<2$ for all but finitely many $n$, we have $2-\overline{a} >0$. Thus, 
$$1\leq (2-\overline{a})\overline{a}.$$
Then it follows that $(\overline{a}-1)^2 \leq 0$, which yields $\overline{a}=1$.

Similar argument for $\underline{a}$ gives $\underline{a}=1$. Therefore, $a_n\rightarrow 1$.

**Proof of My try 2**

Since $a_n=0$ or $a_n=2$ do not happen infinitely often, we may assume that $a_n\neq 0$, $a_n\neq 2$ for all $n$.

Consider $\{1/k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, and the sequence given by the recurrence:
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1+\frac1 1}{2-a_n}. \ \ \textrm{(Round 1)}
$$
Then there exists $n$ such that $a_n>2$. We will put the first time that it happens as $n=n_1$, and we will say that we exit the Round 1. We have $a_{n_1+1}<0$ by the recurrence.

Once we exit the Round 1, we enter into the Round 2 which starts with $n=n_1+1$ and the recurrence: 
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1+\frac12}{2-a_n}. \ \ \textrm{(Round 2)}
$$
Then there exists $n$ such that $a_n>2$. We put the first time $n\geq n_1+1$ that it happens as $n=n_2$, and we exit the Round 2. Then $a_{n_2+1}<0$.

Continue this process with using the recurrence 
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1+\frac1k}{2-a_n}. \ \ \textrm{(Round $k$)}
$$

Then we have the sequcne $a_n$ such that $a_n>2$ infinitely many often and $(2-a_n)a_{n+1}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Would be nice if you could tell us how did you obtain the sequence, and what sequence was it for which it's false.

Comment: Not sure, but Isn't $a_n \sim a_{n+1}$ so that $(2-a_n)(a_n) \sim 1$ and thus $a_n \sim 1$.

Comment: $a_n=(-1)^n+1$.

Comment: @MyGlasses That sequence $a_n$ is $2$ infinitely many often. So, it does not satisfy the condition $(2-a_n)a_{n+1} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @kingW3 I will upload the proofs of my tries 1 and 2 soon.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla That's what I thought too when I first saw the problem. After trying few small numbers, you will see that we do not have $a_n\sim a_{n+1}$ without further assumptions.

Comment: What textbook is this from?

Comment: That was a textbook I read 16 years ago, and it was a translated text. Sorry for not having the exact reference.

Comment: You can construct a bounded counterexample similar to what you already have: let's denote $f_c(x)=c/(2-x)$, then for every positive integer $k$ there is $c_k>1$ such that $-0.5<f_{c_k}(-0.5)<f_{c_k}(f_{c_k}(-0.5))<...<f_{c_k}^{(k)}(-0.5) = 1.75$. These $c_k$ form a decreasing sequence with limit $1$. Let Round $k$ consist of $k+2$ terms: $-0.5, f_{c_k}(-0.5), f_{c_k}(f_{c_k}(-0.5)), ..., f_{c_k}^{(k)}(-0.5) = 1.75, 4$. Then, if $a_n$ belongs to the Round $k$, then $(2-a_n)a_{n+1}$ is either $c_k$ or 1, so the limit of $(2-a_n)a_{n+1}$ is 1, and $a_n$ is bounded by -0.5 below and 4 above.

Comment: @Litho thank you. Would you put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to construct a bounded counterexample in a way similar to what you have done:  let's denote $f_c(x)=c/(2-x)$, then for every positive integer $k$ there is $c_k>1$ such that $-0.5<f_{c_k}(-0.5)<f_{c_k}(f_{c_k}(-0.5))<...<f_{c_k}^{(k)}(-0.5) = 1.75$. These $c_k$ form a decreasing sequence with limit $1$. Let Round $k$ consist of $k+2$ terms: $-0.5, f_{c_k}(-0.5), f_{c_k}(f_{c_k}(-0.5)), ..., f_{c_k}^{(k)}(-0.5) = 1.75, 4$. Then, if $a_n$ belongs to the Round $k$, then $(2-a_n)a_{n+1}$ is either $c_k$ or $1$, so the limit of $(2-a_n)a_{n+1}$ is $1$, and $a_n$ is bounded by $-0.5$ from below and by $4$ from above.

Comment: One question: How can we make sure that we arrive at 1.75 in exactly $k$ steps?

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thanks! This is very good.